# Firebase Error: User does not have access

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am working on a snapchat clone where I want to use the image which is cliked on webcam to store in firestore and use it as preview. The code is perfect but it's showing an error related to firebase. I have no idea what to do.
This is my code

```
import "./Preview.css"
import { resetCameraImage, selectCameraImage } from './../features/cameraSlice';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import TextFieldsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/TextFields";
import CreateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Create";
import NoteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Note";
import MusicNoteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MusicNote";
import AttachFileIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AttachFile";
import CropIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Crop";
import TimerIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Timer";
import SendIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Send";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { db, storage } from "./firebase";
import  firebase  from 'firebase';

function Preview() {

    const cameraImage = useSelector(selectCameraImage);
    const history = useHistory();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!cameraImage) {
            history.replace('/');
        }
    }, [cameraImage, history]);

    const closePreview = () => {
        dispatch(resetCameraImage());
    }

    const sendPost = () => {
        const id = uuid();
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`posts/${id}`).putString(cameraImage, "data_url");

        uploadTask.on('state_changed', null, (error) => {
            // error function
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
            // complete function
            storage.ref('posts').child(id).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                db.collection('posts').add({
                    imageUrl: url,
                    username: "PAPA React",
                    read: false,
                    //profilePic,
                    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                });
                history.replace('/chats');
            });
        }
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="preview">
            <CloseIcon className="preview__close" onClick={closePreview}/>
            <div className="preview__toolbarRight">
                <TextFieldsIcon />
                <CreateIcon />
                <NoteIcon />
                <MusicNoteIcon />
                <AttachFileIcon />
                <CropIcon />
                <TimerIcon />
            </div>
            <img src={cameraImage} alt="" />
            <div className="preview__footer" onClick={sendPost} >
                <h2>Send Now</h2>
                <SendIcon fontSize="small" className="preview__sendIcon" />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Preview
```

**Error thrown**

[image: This is the error which I am facing]

**My firebase rule settings**

[image: This is my firebase rule settings]

**Same error on an alternate method**

[image: I also tried this method but the error is same]

**Same error on an alternate method**

[image: Same error thrown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error said the users does not have access to your Firebase Storage. Add rules for Firebase Storage to give users access. For example:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the right way to do it-                                                                                 
`rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Please check the step I shown in the new image still getting the same error. Have no idea what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you overwrite this config to your Firestore rules. Firebase Storage has the own rules config, go to your firebase console, select project then click Storage and go to Rules panel.